# cookie not setting in chrome in MERN stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cookies, server

I am trying to save jwttoken in cookie with node.js but it is not setting there even if I `console.log` the variable which is setting the cookie it also shows cookie saved but its not setting in the browser I don't know why.

here is the code:

login.js:

```
  const postData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = user;
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
    }).then((response) => { return response.json() })
      .then((data) => { data ? navigate('/') : console.log('There\'s error Logging in, please try again later.') })
  }
```

userController.js:

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log(email);
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) return next(new Error('Email does not exist'));
    const validPassword = await validatePassword(password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) return next(new Error('Password is not correct'))
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "1d"
    });
    const coki = res.cookie('jwtToken', accessToken, { expiresIn: "1d", httpOnly: true })
    if (coki) {
      console.log('cookie set!');
    }
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { accessToken })
    res.status(200).json({
      data: { email: user.email, role: user.role },
      accessToken
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

there is more code other then this but this is the main login code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things you need to set to enable http only cookie.

1. Set Cors policy first

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);
```

2. While saving cookie, do it in this way.

```js
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
  path: "/",
  sameSite: "strict",
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
});
```

3. Set credentials to true while making the api call from frontend

```js
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

4. Maybe to parse cookie every time you would need to add cookie parser also. Its not needed though.

```js
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: brother you are god you have helped me a lot tere was no solution given any where but you helped me so much it's really working thank you so mcuh brother 